# Most performant storage for very large postgres data directory on Docker for Mac?

Tags: docker, docker-for-mac

I’m exploring using Docker for Mac for my local development environment. Most things are pretty clear but I’m wondering what the best approach to storage for my Postgres data directory is. My company uses full snapshots of our very large production database in development, so that adds some constraints. “Best” in this case translates roughly to whatever will be most performant.

Currently I’m using a bind mount, so the data directory lives on my host machine. This works fine. Container storage is pretty clearly a non-starter. Volumes seem like a potentially good alternative, but using the `local` volume type results in running out of space when the `Docker.qcow2` file fills up. I know there are many other volume drivers but it’s not clear if any of them are particularly good for this use case, or if I should just stick with a bind mount.

Answer (score 1):

I think the most performant is the mount on the host, just because it is local and native. As far as I know, other drivers are often made to use remote (so less performant) storages.

For development, keep your bind mount.